# Xubuntu - Stop XFCE from running at boot

Tags: linux, vnc, xubuntu

Here is what I'm trying to do.

My computer is connected to my TV with Kodi running.  I want to be able to VNC into an XFCE desktop while kodi is still running on the main screen.

The first issue is that I added startxfce4 to .vnc/xstartup but I just get a gray X screen and an error in the logs about an XFCE session already running.

So I thought my solution would be to run just Kodi on top of X with no XFCE and just run XFCE on the vnc session.

I can't figure out how to get XFCE to stop starting at boot.  I removed lightdm from rc.* but it still starts.  What is pulling it in?